# How do I remove the dotted line under the image?

Tags: html, image, css, hyperlink, responsive-design

I don't really know why this line is showing up. I didn't do anything weird in the HTML. The only thing I did was put an img inside a link so I could use the img as a link/button. For some reason there are these lines below the picture (pictured below) that is just very displeasing so look at. How do I remove it?

[image: Example]

Any advice?

Comment: a{text-decoration:none;} ^^

Answer (score 0):

I assume, that as you said - its the default underline of a link.

So

```
a{text-decoration:none;}
```

should do the trick

If that doesn't help then a code sample and / or fiddle of your project would help with debugging

Comment: This is the code I'm currently using. I'm fairly new to this so I'm not quite sure if I did anything wrong. 

`<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="3u">
      <a href="#"><img src="images/CLUB1.jpg" class="img-responsive" style='width:100%;'></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>`

Sorry, I can't figure out how to do the formatting of the code. But this is what I'm using. The CSS you provided me with doesn't work.

Comment: please provide an example at codepen.io or jsfiddle. Also tell me which browser you are using :)